# How to SELECT data which have relation with 2 or more data in MANY to MANY tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables in mySQL called tb_tour_trip, tb_facilities and tb_master_facilities which have many to many relationship. I want to select 1 data in tb_tour_trip which have 2 or more master_facilities. example : i wanna select trip which have facilities: AC and WiFi

This is the tb_tour_trip table :

```
tb_tour_trip
============
id || name  || description  || price
===================================
1  || trip1 || example trip || $200
2  || trip2 || example trip || $300
```

This is the tb_facilities table (For MANY to MANY relations):

```
tb_facilities
============
id || id_master_facilities_ref || id_tour_trip_ref
===================================
1  || 1                        || 1 
2  || 2                        || 1 
3  || 1                        || 2
3  || 3                        || 2
```

And this is my tb_master_facilities table:

```
tb_master_facilities
============
id || name  || status
====================
1  || WiFi  || 1
2  || AC    || 1
3  || TV    || 1
```

if tried this Query :

```
SELECT id_tour_trip_ref FROM tb_facilities WHERE id_master_facilities_ref IN(1,2);
```

this show me id_tour_trip which have facilities : AC or Wifi, but that's not what i want.

I want the id_tour_trip which have AC AND Wifi only.

Exactly output is just :

```
id_tour_trip_ref
================
1
```

How can i do that? thanks before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found the answer from forum on Facebook. thanks for all your advice :)

This is the exactly i need.

```
SELECT id_tour_trip_ref, GROUP_CONCAT(id_master_facilities_ref) AS facilities FROM tb_facilities GROUP BY id_tour_trip_ref HAVING FIND_IN_SET('1', facilities) > 0 AND FIND_IN_SET('2', facilities) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a number of ways to do this, but a reasonably easy to read/maintain method is this:

```
SELECT id
FROM tb_tour_trip AS ttt
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id_master_facilities_ref)
    FROM tb_facilities AS tbf
    WHERE tbf.id_tour_trip_ref = ttt.id
    AND tbf.id_master_facilities_ref IN (1, 2)
) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If only to get your exact output, this could also work:

`SELECT id_tour_trip_ref 
FROM tb_facilities INNER JOIN tb_master_facilities ON tb_facilities.id=tb_master_facilities.id 
WHERE name IN ("WiFi","AC") AND id_master_facilities_ref IN (1,2)
GROUP BY id_tour_trip_ref;`

Comment: On a side note, I would like to share something: Try not to use column name such as NAME or STATUS because these are also MySQL function. In some cases, you'll get a different results when executing a query. :)

Comment: i just described my tables name and fileld name in a nutshell, coz the real one use another language (not english). i do that only for the best understanding situation. but thanks for the advice.

Comment: Ok @ferigalung ;)

Answer (score 0):

One method is aggregation with a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT f.id_tour_trip_ref 
FROM tb_facilities f INNER JOIN
     tb_master_facilities
     ON f.id = mf.id 
WHERE f.name IN ('WiFi', 'AC') 
GROUP BY f.id_tour_trip_ref
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would join all of the tables together and just do 'where condition1 and condition2. This is propably less efficient but imho more comprehensive.

```
select distinct tb_tour_trip.id from tb_tour_trip 

inner join tb_facilities on tb_facilities.id_tour_trip_ref = tb_tour_trip.id
inner join tb_master_facilities on tb_master_facilities.id = tb_facilities.id_master_facilities_ref 

where tb_master_facilities.name = 'WiFi'
and tb_master_facilities.name = 'AC'
```

Comment: ive tried this one, and didn't show anything, even the data is exist in that conditions.

Comment: HI, Sorry I misunderstood the relation between the tables tb_facilities and tb_master_facilities. The answer e_i_pi wrote should give you the desired result.